# Identifying referring page with javascript

Tags: javascript, history

Hey, I have setup error pages for http errors, and I have IIS 6 pointing to the various pages for the different errors.

What I'd like to do, is configure the actual error page to fire an email as soon as its loaded (onLoad event I believe) to a specific address, containing information about the error in question, which page the user was at before the error was encountered, etc.

Basically, how do I identify what the user's referring url was? Say he was on www.whatever.com/products.html, and he clicked on 'Cart', which resulted in a 404 error, I know how to capture the error type (IIS points to my 404 specific error file, simple enough), but not which page it came from (products.html).

I've tried 'history.previous', and 'document.referrer', and neither appear to work.

Site is in asp, (not .net), and portions are being migrated to html5...

Answer (score 0):

See here : http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/javascript_no14.htm for information on document.referrer

Comment: Hey, I've seen that document already... Doesn't help, as it doesn't tell me the address of the page that brought me to the new page to begin with. 

What I really want, is when someone is on page1.html, and they go to page2.html, there should be a notification - "You have come from page1.html", if they used page220.html, the notification should say so too...